# Radio buttons group jquery click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, input

i have 4 radio buttons hidden under each image inside each div.

```
   <div class="temp-inner" id="someid">
        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){?>
            <div data-id="<?=$row['id'];?>" class="hand  temp-selector">
                <input type="radio" name="templates_id" class="templates_id" value="<?=$row['id'];?>" />
                <label class="temp-type" style="background-image:url(<?=$row['src'];?>)"></label>
            </div>
        <? } ?>
   </div>
```

i need to make radio button under image = checked, so i decided to create onClick function

```
$(".hand").on("click", function() {
    $(this).children("input:radio[name=templates_id]").attr('checked',true); 
}
```

this part works perfect. Now i want to add new class to whole  if radio button is checked under it. i thought that i can use if - else statement, but it doesn't work.

```
$(".hand").on("click", function() {
    $(this).children("input:radio[name=templates_id]").attr('checked',true); 

    if($("input:radio[name=templates_id]").is(":checked")) {
        $(".hand").addClass("active");
    } else {
        $(".hand").removeClass("active");
    } 
};
```

How can i write it correctly? Thx a lot, best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will check the radio on the div clicked, remove the active class on every div with hand class and add the active class to the div clicked.

```
$(document).on('click', '.hand', function () {
    $(this).children("input:radio[name=templates_id]").prop('checked', true);
    $(".hand").removeClass("active");
    $(this).closest("div.hand").addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: sure i can toggleClass .. but i need to remove it if radio - unchecked.

```$(".hand").on("click", function() {
 $(this).children("input:radio[name=templates_id]").attr('checked',true);
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
``` In this case - it'll just add class to all div's that was clicked, i need only one checked radio .. and div.active with it

Comment: How do you uncheck you radio? There's only code for checking it. I edited my answer with code to uncheck the radio.

Comment: i thought i don't need to uncheck radio .. it just checkes next one

Comment: @Yevgen Does my last edit to my answer worked for you ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use length property, try:

```
$(".hand").on("click", function() {
    $(this).children("input:radio[name=templates_id]").attr('checked',true); 

    if($("input:radio[name=templates_id]").length > 0) {
        $(".hand").addClass("active");
    } else {
        $(".hand").removeClass("active");
    } 
};
```